# How to set relative path for C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py in RED.xml?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I'm setting up a Selenium project using robot framework. In one of my test cases, I use Library called " Selenium "  in the *** Setting *** section of the test case. The same library is added to the red.xml. But the eclipse validate the project and throws a warning "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The path C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/**init**.py is absolute. RED prefers using workspace-relative paths which makes your projects more portable  red.xml line 15 Robot Problem
"
How to enter the relative path for the selenium Library or how to remove the warning?

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup    Load Suite Data  

Library    SeleniumLibrary    
Library    Collections
```

In red.xml it is

```
SeleniumLibrary-C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py
```

The warning should be removed from red.xml

Comment: I tried as defined, but still, I see the warning in red.xml for SeleniumLibrary. Kindly provide more info if possible...